# search multiple values using excel vba

Tags: vba, excel

Below code helps to search a value entered in cell `K8` and return values related to it. I need help searching multiple values, all values entered in range `K8:K30` need to be searched, and records related to them need to be displayed.

```
Sub finddata()
    Dim emstring As String

    Dim finalrow As Integer
    Dim i As Integer

    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("P3:X37").ClearContents

    emstring = Sheets("sheet1").Range("K8").Value
    finalrow = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A6000").End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 2 To finalrow
        If Cells(i, 2) = emstring Then
          Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 3)).Copy
          Range("P6000").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulasAndNumberFormats
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go, a nested For Loop with extra length checking:

```
Sub finddata()
    Dim emstring As String

    Dim finalrow As Integer
    Dim i As Integer

    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("P3:X37").ClearContents

    emstring = Sheets("sheet1").Range("K8").Value
    finalrow = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A6000").End(xlUp).Row

    Dim ctrSearchRow As Integer

        For i = 2 To finalrow
            For ctrSearchRow = 8 To 30
                emstring = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(ctrSearchRow, 11).Value
                If Len(emstring) > 0 Then
                    If StrComp(Cells(i, 2).Value, emstring, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
                        Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 3)).Copy
                        Range("P6000").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulasAndNumberFormats
                    End If
                End If
            Next ctrSearchRow
        Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

[AutoFilter()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193884.aspx) use with its `Operator` argument set to `xlFilterValues` can give a help in hand here:

```
Sub finddata()
    With Sheets("Sheet1")
        .Range("P3:X37").ClearContents
        With .Range("B1", .Cells(.Rows.count, 2).End(xlUp)) '<--| reference column "B" range from row 1 (header) down to last not empty row
            .AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:=Application.Transpose(.Parent.Range("K8:K30").Value), Operator:=xlFilterValues '<--| filter on all K8:K30 values
            If Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(103, .Cells) > 1 Then '<--| if any filtered cell found
                .Offset(1, -1).Resize(.Rows.count - 1, 3).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy '<-- copy filtered range offsetted one column to the right and resized to three columns
                .Parent.Cells(.Rows.count, "P").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulasAndNumberFormats '<--| paste special
            End If
        End With
        .AutoFilterMode = False
    End With
End Sub
```